# parsing a document with HTML::TableExtract [Perl] to fetch only some labels and values [row by row]

Tags: perl, parsing

good evening dear community,

first of all - i am very very happy that i have found this great place. I like this forum very very much, since it has a great and supportive community! I learn alot form you folks here! Each question has got some great reviewers and - each thread is a rich value and learning asset.

Well i am farily new to Perl - and fairly new to this board here: i am currently workin out a little parser: i want to parse a table

[click here to see the target url- with the very simple table (some rows only)](http://www.schulministerium.nrw.de/BP/SchuleSuchen?action=607.590098597145&SchulAdresseMapDO=154763)

This page has a table: well a table with vaules and lables. We need to provide something that uniquely identifies the table in question. This can be the content of its headers or the HTML attributes. In this case, there is only one table in the document, so we don't even need to do that. But, what about to provide anything to the constructor, I would provide the class of the table.
We do not want the columns of the table. The first column of this table consists of labels and the second column consists of values. To get the labels and values at the same time, we should process the table row-by-row. Well - can this be done like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use YAML;

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(
    attribs => { class => 'bp_ergebnis_tab_info' },
);

$te->parse_file('t.html');
# here the file with the captured site is stored 

foreach my $table ( $te->tables ) { 
    foreach my $row ($table->rows) {
        print "   ", join(',', @$row), "\n";
    }
}
```

See the results:

```
 martin@suse-linux:~/perl> perl  parser_perl_nrw2.pl
 Use of uninitialized value $row in join or string at parser_perl_nrw2.pl line 17.
  Schuldaten,
  Schule hat Schulbetrieb
  Schulnummer,143960

   Amtliche Bezeichnung,�Franziskusschule Kath. Hauptschule Ahaus - Sekundarstufe I -

   Strasse,Hof zum Ahaus 6

   Plz und Ort,48683 Ahaus

   Telefon,02561 4291990

   Fax,02561 42919920

   E-Mail-Adresse,143960@schule.nrw.de


   Internet,http://www.franziskusschule.de
  ,Schule in �ffentlicher Tr�gerschaft
```

WELL i want to get the data that are shown above - but if you see below - there are some more lines of text and code, ... talking like so. (/i **want to´get rid** of these following lines!!!)

```
Use of uninitialized value $row in join or string at parser_perl_nrw2.pl
line 17.
,Schülergesamtzahl,648
Use of uninitialized value $row in join or string at parser_perl_nrw2.pl
line 17.
,Ganztagsunterricht,Ja (erweiterter Ganztagsbetrieb)
Sonstiges,Teilnahme am Projekt 'Betrieb und Schule (BUS)'
Use of uninitialized value $row in join or string at parser_perl_nrw2.pl
line 17.
Unterrichtsangebote,
Use of uninitialized value $row in join or string at parser_perl_nrw2.pl
line 17.
Schule erteilt Unterricht in Fremdsprache(n)...,
,Englisch
```

**Question:** how do i get rid of the unsanitized data! All is nice - but i want to get  rid of the unsanitized data... that is very very ugly - and since i want to store the data into a database - i do not need the unsanitized data...!

As allways: any and all help will be greatly appreciated - many thanks in advance!

regards
zero

Comment: If you really appreciate this forum so much, how about you accept some answers to your questions?

Comment: mobrule, if you want to modify the behaviour of the newbies, how about you throw them a bone and link to the appropriate documentation? They do not understand the jargon - such as [accept answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) - yet and are overwhelmed by the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get rid of the uninitialized value warnings?

Some of the table cells are empty so you may want to test for them or filter them out. Like this for example:

```
foreach my $table ( $te->tables ) {
        foreach my $row ($table->rows) {
        my @values = grep {defined} @$row;
        print "   ", join(',', @values), "\n";
       }
    }
```

You could also outright disable warnings for that particular block with `no warnings ' uninitialized'`, but it is generally not a good practice.

Comment: hello jira - many many thanks for the answer. GREAT !! I will try out all you advice! AGAIN  thx! this is a very very good place to be!! Have a great day!